# how to get the non-repetitive element from two variables in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am running the Ansible task for creating terraform resources, code is below:

```yaml
- name: "Run terraform project: {{ tf_project }}"
  terraform:
    state: present
    force_init: true
    backend_config:
      bucket: "{{ tf_bucket_name }}"
      region: "{{ bootstrap_region }}"
      kms_key_id: "{{ tf_bucket_kms_id }}"
      encrypt: "true"
      workspace_key_prefix: "{{ target_infra }}"
      key: "{{ tf_project }}.tfstate"
    project_path: "../terraform_12/{{ tf_project }}"
    variables:
      target_region: XXXXXXX
    workspace: "Test"
```

below are the values of the variables:

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname]['Active_Regions']: ['eu-west-1','ap-southeast-2']
hostvars[inventory_hostname]['Region']:  'eu-west-1'
```

expected value:
target_region: `['ap-southeast-2']`

have tried below:

```yaml
target_region: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['Active_Regions'] | difference(hostvars[inventory_hostname]['Region'] | list) }}"
```

but it's not working.

note: `hostvars[inventory_hostname]['Active_Regions']` and `hostvars[inventory_hostname]['Regions']` are dynamic.

Comment: _but it's not working_ > this is not a good description of a problem, what is not working? Do you get an error, if yes, please [edit] it in your question. Is the `target_region` just blank? Else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is not a list. You have to enclose it in brackets `[]`, e.g.

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      target_region: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['Active_Regions']|
             difference([hostvars[inventory_hostname]['Region']]) }}"
```